# It is allowed to play and make video games?

Tags: halal-haram, software, game

I want to know if it's allowed to play and develop video games. I wanted to make one but after, I realize that the game must contains characters, music so I decided to make a Qur'an app. I told myself that I'm sure with that to do the things halal and Allah will help me, but now I've posted it on the store and the app didn't succeed.

I've put months and months of effort day and night but now i'm desperate. I'm thinking to come back to games now. I just need to know if it's halal or haram first?

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the replies on the others questions do not satisfied me[Sorry for my bad english again]. They talk about waste time, violent video games etc. but not about representations, music that is in games generally...

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24851/is-game-development-permissible-in-islam?rq=1 this has a brief answer.

Answer (score -1):

Brother, what makes you think that video games are haram ? Because it contains character drawings ? Did you hear anybody saying cartoon movies are haram ? They are the same.

The answer is : if the video game or cartoon movie contains explicit material or encourages bad behaviour, do not do it. Otherwise, it is Halal inshaallah :)

P.S : about the Quran app, or any other charity action you will do : you will be rewarded by thawab from Almighty for your good intentions and  efforts , not for the results. So do not get desperate or feel sorrowful ever for any good action you do, ever :)

God bless you.